# Visual Studio multiple copy and paste

Tags: visual-studio, copy-paste

While editing and fixing up code I have thought that sometimes it would be nice to be able to paste more than one thing at a time. For instance I was fixing up some WCF Rest code and I wanted to paste "Xml" sometimes and "Json" other times. These are easy to type, but a keyboard shortcut is much easier

Thus, is it possible to have multiple different items in the copy memory and then to paste them individually?

Comment: Use a piece of software called `ditto-cp` - clipboard on steroids; history, direct quick paste of 10 things, network sharing of clipboard..

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Use CTRL-Shift-V multiple times (until you have the text you want)

Comment: I have VS 2008. Doesn't seem to work. Did you have to re-assign your shortcut keys?

Comment: @Sundar Ctrl+Shift+Ins in my copy of VS2008. It's present since VS 2003: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa301782%28VS.71%29.aspx

Comment: Not sure if that was an intentional typo @lsalamon, but amusing nonetheless.

Comment: So after spending near 20 years of my life with VS, I learned something new today.

Answer (score 10):

For the ones who are looking for it, as I was.
The name of the action you want to perform is Edit.CycleClipboardRing.
In my VS2008, it was assigned to the keys Ctrl+Shift+Insert. Just changed to Ctrl+Shift+V in Tools->Options...->Keyboard.

Answer (score 6):

When there is text that I want to repeatedly enter in a source file, I type it once, select it and drag and drop it to the Toolbox tool window (you can even rename the snippet name if you want).

Then when I want to use it, I drag and drop it from the toolbox tool window to the source file.

Answer (score 3):

I've been using [Clipx](http://www.bluemars.org/clipx/) for years. You can access your older clipboard items with ctrl-shift-v.

Plus this works with all programs: you can copy your source snippets in notepad or outlook.

Answer (score -1):

I prefer using [FlyCut](https://github.com/TermiT/Flycut). It shows the last 30 results and app name as well from where you've copied the content. There's an option for handling `copy` from password fields.